# why the html code doesnt linked with the css code?

Tags: html, css

> here is the code I used for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Github Hub </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div><img src="C:\Users\Maryam\Pictures\Saved Pictures\github.logo.jpg" width="205" height="150" /></div>
    <div>This is <i>site for Github</i> to search for interesting peojrcts.</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="/index.html">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="/abouy.html">About</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<section id="main">
    <p>We will show you a list of <b> Github projects</b><span> and the dates</span>, (click here for more information <a href="http://github.com">Gethub</a>).</p>
    <form action="http://wilder.azurewebsites.net/echo" method="post">
        <label for="SearchPhrase">Search Phrase:</label>
        <input name="SearchPhrase" id="Searchphrase" /> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="UseStars" /> <label for="UseStars"> Use Stars?</label> <br />
        <label for="LangChoice">Languages:</label><br />
        <select name="langChoice" id="langChoice">
            <option selected>All</option>
            <option>JavaScript</option>
            <option>Java</option>
            <option>C#</option>
            <option>Ruby</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="search" />

</form>
</section>
<footer>
    &copy; 2020 Mariam Shabou LLC
</footer>
```

> here is the code I used for site.css
> i linked HTML with CSS but the problem once i run the work doesn't appear in the web

```
/*site.css*/
    header, footer {
        background: lightgrey;
        border: solid 1px black;
        /**font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif,**/
    }
    footer{
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    body{
        font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #main{
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #main > form > label
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

> here is what i got when i run the code of index.html and the problem is the code that i wrote in site.css is not linked to index.hmtl means the modyified in site.css doesnt exists.

[image]

Comment: You probably got the URL of the CSS wrong.

Comment: Open the dev tools and check if you're getting a 200 response on the CSS path

Comment: If you are certain this is the correct location, try using `./css/site.css` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your relative path. On everything else, you're leading with a slash, which makes me think you probably need one before your CSS path, but without looking at your filesystem it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your screenshots this appears it might be a classic **File Path** error. It looks like your **index.html** is located in `localhost/img/index.html`

Where does your **CSS** live?

If it lives in `localhost/img/css/style.css` your code should work fine.

If it lives in `localhost/css/style.css` then you need to change the location of your CSS to the following;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/site.css">
```

the `../` tells the href to go back a directory, then go in to CSS. Without the `../` you are telling it to look in the current directory, which by your screenshot it would be; `localhost/img/css/style.css`.

When using File Paths that way; you have to be mindful that it is RELATIVE to where the current document exists.

Take a read of these articles relating to **File Paths**;

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: "the ./ tells the href to go back a directory" - Isn't it ".."?

Comment: Oh shoot, yes! Fixed. @GalaxyCat105 nice spotting. My bad. Didn't realise I used '.' instead of '..'!

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you share the folder structure of your current project.

However, there are few common mistakes seems obvious in your code such as loading something from absolute file directory (`C:\`) which makes me believe you are using static files only and is not recommended at all.

If these front-end code is part of a bigger project such as using c#, php etc., you could easily use `base_url` concept and load the files via the publicly accessible absolute url such as `http://localhost/yourproject/site.css` or `http://yourdomain.com/css/site.css`.

In any cases, like many of us trying to point to you that, it is about the relative path of the CSS file you have. That should fix your problem now and will guaranteed to work even if you move the server.